# _@[^@]*@ in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell

every one, i've a problem about this expression in a **shell script**:

```
expr "$VERSION" : "_@[^@]*@"
```

Who can tell me what does "@" stand for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man expr`:

```
 expr1 : expr2
         The ``:'' operator matches expr1 against expr2, which must be a
         regular expression.  The regular expression is anchored to the
         beginning of  the string with an implicit ``^''.  expr expects
         "basic" regular expressions, see re_format(7) for more informa-
         tion on regular expressions.
```

`@` is just `@`, as it has no special meaning in a regular expression. Thus,

```
expr _@foo@ : "_@[^@]*@"
```

will succeed, and output `6` (it being the number of matched characters); while

```
expr _x@foo@ : "_@[^@]*@"
```

will output `0` and return a failure code in `$?`, as it could not match anything.

If you are not familiar with regular expressions, the one given in your example means: an underscore (`_`) followed two at-signs (`@`) sandwiching any number of non-at-sign characters.

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation, I tried to find the '@' from regular expression reference, but fail. It seems only the validation of the $VERSION number, which meaningless ...

Comment: @krime: just to add that `[^@]*` means "zero of more characters that are *not* @".

Answer (score 1):

It's just a literal `@`.  The `@` has no special meaning in the regex, although it may in `$VERSION`.

Matches "underscore followed by @ followed by zero or more non-@ characters followed by @."

Comment: I've try some tests, that's true. Thanks~!